# Algorithm help: divide a matrix to N continuous cells, with close to equal sum of items

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have an integers matrix A with `R` rows and `C` cols.
I would like to implement a function `f(mat A, uint N)` to divide the matrix into continuous N cells, all of the together covering the whole matrix area, such as the sum of the items in each cell `i1 ... iN` is as closer to be equal as possible.
So far I started with a simple, expensive implementation that first starts with `N/2 x N/2` simple grid, compute the sum for each cell, and adjusts the grid lines iteratively.
Obviously, it is not optimal neither in runtime nor optimal solution, and also limited to rectangle cells only that share the horizontal and vertical limits with other cells.

Could you please advice me on how should I solve this? 
(My current solution produces something like:

```
---------------------------
|        |          |     |
---------------------------
|        |          |     |
|        |          |     |
---------------------------
|        |          |     |
---------------------------
```

or

```
---------------------------
|       | |               |
|       | |               |
|       | |               |
---------------------------
|       | |               |
|       | |               |
---------------------------
|       | |               |
---------------------------
```

)

I hope the details are clear, please let me know if anything needs clarification.

Thank you!

Comment: *[...] limited to rectangle cells only that share the horizontal and vertical limits with other cells.* Does this mean, that the cells don't even need to be aligned? Something which would look like a mondrian painting would be fine too?

Comment: Yes. Polygons, mondrian painting, whatever - you name it. As long as it works. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't even have to be rectangles.. sounds tough

Comment: So a "cell" should be any contiguous area?

Comment: @user31264: yes, it has to be contiguous. However a simplified version with rectangles only is also ok.

Comment: Try simulated annealing.

Comment: @user31264: Could you please extend this to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in part, note that the problem you describe contains the [Partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) as a subproblem, which is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness); hence, the problem in your question is also [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) which makes the existence of an efficient algorithm very unlikely.

Comment: Thanks @Codor !
Is it still NP-Complete when adding the mitigation of using only a grid of straight lines (like in my naive solution, optimizing the vertical / horizontal shifting policy only?